# The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Im using spring boot to create an app that has 4 databases types: h2, mongodb, redis and neo4j.

I've implemented the h2 and mongodb code.

Im going to use the aggregatedRating entity example.

The logic I have is a uri in my application.properties, a controller with the endpoint, service interface, service implementation, AggregatedRatingRepository, AggregatedRatingRepositoryMongo and AggregatedRatingRepositoryImpl. I have also a mongoConfig where I config the Mongo template.

Here is the code:

**MongoConfig**

```
package com.isep.acme.config;

import com.isep.acme.model.mongoDomain.*;
import com.isep.acme.repositories.*;
import com.isep.acme.repositories.mongo.*;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Collections;

@Profile("mongo")
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.isep.acme.repositories.mongo")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class MongoConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String mongoPrivateUri;

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoPrivateUri));
    }


}
```

**AggregatedRatingService**

```
package com.isep.acme.services;

import com.isep.acme.model.AggregatedRating;

public interface AggregatedRatingService {

    AggregatedRating save(String sku);
}
```

** AggregatedRatingServiceImpl **

```
package com.isep.acme.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.isep.acme.model.AggregatedRating;
import com.isep.acme.model.Product;
import com.isep.acme.repositories.AggregatedRatingRepository;
import com.isep.acme.repositories.ProductRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class AggregatedRatingServiceImpl implements AggregatedRatingService{

    @Autowired
    AggregatedRatingRepository arRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository pRepository;

    @Autowired
    ReviewService rService;

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @Override
    public AggregatedRating save( String sku ) {

        Optional<Product> product = pRepository.findBySku( sku );

        if (product.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

        Double average = rService.getWeightedAverage(product.get());


        Optional<AggregatedRating> r = arRepository.findByProductId(product.get());
        AggregatedRating aggregateF;

        if(r.isPresent()) {
            r.get().setAverage( average );
            aggregateF = (AggregatedRating) arRepository.save(r.get());
        }
        else {
            AggregatedRating f = new AggregatedRating(average, product.get());
            aggregateF = (AggregatedRating) arRepository.save(f);
        }

        return aggregateF;
    }


}
```

**AggregatedRatingRepository**

```
package com.isep.acme.repositories;

import com.isep.acme.model.Product;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface AggregatedRatingRepository<T,L> extends CrudRepository<T, Long>{

    Optional<T> findByProductId(Product product);

}
```

**AggregatedRatingMongoRepository**

```
package com.isep.acme.repositories.mongo;

import com.isep.acme.model.Product;
import com.isep.acme.model.mongoDomain.AggregatedRatingMongo;
import com.isep.acme.repositories.AggregatedRatingRepository;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

import java.util.Optional;

@Profile("mongo")
public interface AggregatedRatingMongoRepository extends AggregatedRatingRepository<AggregatedRatingMongo,Long>, MongoRepository<AggregatedRatingMongo, Long> {

    @Query("{'product.sku':?0}")
    Optional<AggregatedRatingMongo> findByProductId(Product product);
}
```

**AggregatedRatingMongoRepositoryImpl**

```
package com.isep.acme.repositories.mongo.impl;

import com.isep.acme.model.Product;
import com.isep.acme.model.mongoDomain.AggregatedRatingMongo;
import com.isep.acme.repositories.mongo.AggregatedRatingMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.FluentQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Repository
@Profile("mongo")
@Primary
public class AggregatedRatingMongoRepositoryImpl implements AggregatedRatingMongoRepository {

    private final AggregatedRatingMongoRepository repo;
    @Autowired
    public AggregatedRatingMongoRepositoryImpl(@Qualifier("aggregatedRatingMongoRepository") AggregatedRatingMongoRepository aggregatedRatingMongoRepository) {
        this.repo = aggregatedRatingMongoRepository;
    }

 ... all the methods implemented by default from mongo (save, saveall, getbyid, etc)
```

My application.properties looks like this:

```
# swagger-ui custom path
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui

## JWT
jwt.private.key=classpath:rsa.private.key
jwt.public.key=classpath:rsa.public.key

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/acme;MV_STORE=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=true;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=gg
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
# access h2 console at http://localhost:8080/h2-console  

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB

file.upload-dir=DEV/FileUploads

## Logging
logging.level.com.example.demo=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

## Profiles
spring.profiles.active=bootstrap,mongo

##Set sku method
sku.creation.method=method1
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://myinfo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

**Error**:

The problem here is that I'm facing this error:

```
2023-11-04 21:14:07.539 ERROR 13436 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   aggregatedRatingController (field com.isep.acme.services.AggregatedRatingService com.isep.acme.controllers.AggregatedRatingController.aService)
      ↓
   aggregatedRatingServiceImpl (field com.isep.acme.repositories.AggregatedRatingRepository com.isep.acme.services.AggregatedRatingServiceImpl.arRepository)
┌─────┐
|  aggregatedRatingMongoRepositoryImpl defined in file [C:mylocation\acme\repositories\mongo\impl\AggregatedRatingMongoRepositoryImpl.class]
└─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can't wire in a reference to AggregatedRatingMongoRepository and implement it in the same class. This is what is giving you the circular reference runtime error.

Also, it seems very odd to me and a bit of a code smell to implement your own version of all the CrudRepository methods in AggregatedRatingMongoRepositoryImpl. This seems very odd given that the entire point of implementing CrudRepository gives you all the CRUD operations for free without the need to implement them yourself. If you just wired in AggregatedRatingRepository without implementing it you wouldn't have to do that. The moment you implement AggregatedRatingRepository further down in your inheritance chain requires you to implement everything yourself which should be avoided.